# update field based on another table django

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

hello I have to models I want to run a query every day to update a total field in a weekly table in some conditions first user ids should be equal then start_date in weekly table and date in daily table should be in the same week
i want to set total from weekly table like this
weekly.total = weekly.total + daily.total
please help

```
class Daily(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    total = models.FloatField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)

class Weekly(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    total = models.FloatField(default=0)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)
```

Comment: Welcome @Raven. You'll need to provide some more information as to where the data comes from. What triggers the query to run - are you going to do that manually, or does it run when a user logs in, or do you have a scheduler of some sort in place? Some links on how to ask good questions: [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) | [What types of questions should I avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) | [What topics are encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: THANK YOU. im using celery for scheuling this task.

Comment: Post the model that the data come from; specify what part you are having issues with - the scheduling, the aggregation, the creating the records in daily/weekly, and mention if you are open to another, potentially better, solution than the Daily/Weekly metric tables.